# What is wrong with this SQL Statement using Merge

Tags: sql

```
create procedure [dbo].[teststoredproc] (@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime) as
begin
set nocount on;

merge TargetTable with (tablockx) as target
using (
    select
        S.columnA, S.columnB
    from
        SourceTable S
    where
        S.ModifiedOn >= @startDate and S.ModifiedOn <= @enddate) as source
    (columnA, columnB)
on (target.columnA= source.columnA)
when matched then update set
    target.columnA = source.columnA, target.columnB = source.columnB
when not matched by target then insert
    (columnA, columnB) values (source.columnA, source.columnB);

GO
```

I get the following error when I try to compile the statement:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

at the very last line which is:

```
(columnA, columnB) values (source.columnA, source.columnB);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are missing an END

```
when not matched by target then insert
    (columnA, columnB) values (source.columnA, source.columnB);

END

GO
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that that `end` is to match the `begin` at the top of the stored procedure, and nothing to do with the `merge` statement.